# Why performing Gaussian elimination helps us to find independent columns, does not preserve the column space, but keeps the solution

Tags: linear-algebra

So I am confused about the following:
Gaussian elimination helps us to find pivot columns and thus find independent and dependent columns in the matrix.

BUT Gaussian elimination is operating on row elements. So by operating on rows we somehow reveal dependence of columns.

Gaussian elimination does not preserve the column space of a matrix, but in the same time the solution to the system of linear equations stays the same (while the solution vector must be in the column space of a matrix).

I got really confused about that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Gaussian elimination does not preserve the column space (it does preserve the row space though). However, each time you perform an elementary operation, you basically multiply your original matrix by an invertible matrix. In the language of linear transformations, you act by an isomorphisms (linear invertible operators) and the isomorphisms keep linearly independent columns linearly independent and linearly dependent columns to be linearly dependent. Note that the columns with pivots are linearly independent, and all other columns in the row reduced echelon form can be represented as linear combinations of columns with pivots. Hence the conclusion.